# Cant get peers on rinkeby

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets, peers

After following the instructions on rinkeby for joining the network, I cannot seem to get more than a single peer that also wont get me up to date. Eventually my node kicks that peer off, and then I am isolated.

What is the issue, and how can I troubleshoot/diagnose it?

P.S: no issues syncing to main-net

Edit:
After a while it randomly seems to have have managed to finish syncing, and I now have 3 peers. But my transactions dont reach the network. Geth states that it was submitted, but [etherscan](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x7ffefbc0a02732ea31e9fdbf57f4ad7248113dda2d591d713ecdcd1fc8831e25) doesnt show anything. The [stats](https://www.rinkeby.io/) show my pending transactions seem to reach the network, but nada ;-;

INFO [04-26|01:19:58] Submitted transaction                    fullhash=0x7ffefbc0a02732ea31e9fdbf57f4ad7248113dda2d591d713ecdcd1fc8831e25 recipient=0x55a717fe6247a81b9c1c051364564713f48eefb9

Comment: I am also facing similar kind of issue , but I am getting peer count as 4 ....have got any solution to it

Answer (score 2):

I have had more luck getting peers on geth by using the `--v5disc` cli param (`Enables the experimental RLPx V5 (Topic Discovery) mechanism`).

You should also be running geth 1.8.1+ as it seems there are quite a few changes to the discovery mechanism.

good luck